# What is the appropriate place to ask Artificial Intelligence questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I am confused as to where should I ask programming questions regarding artificial intelligence.
To give a little bit more insight into my question:

I have a working code which is related to artificial intelligence, it works but the AI agent is not working in the most efficient way. I am looking for someone to explain me why is it not the most optimal and how should I fix it.

Two possible places are stackoverflow and code review. Which one is better (or may be there is a better place).

Comment: "Not working in the most efficient way" is ambiguous in this context. Do you mean the code/algorithm is too slow (as the others that answered seem to have interpreted), or is your AI agent not performing in an intelligent manner, ie you are looking for a better approach to solve your AI problem?

Comment: @SchighSchagh I am looking to make my agent more intelligent

Comment: @SalvadorDali You've answered with an even more ambiguous term.

Answer (score 18):

While ChrisF is generally correct - I think it's fine to ask these questions on StackOverflow.

If you have a clear programming problem (code not efficient) and a specific task - and you can create a self contained (perhaps code) sample of your issue that's pretty small - I think it's on-topic here as well as on CodeReview.

Since SO is a much higher traffic site than SE, and since the help you need isn't directly reviewing your code, but rather **struggling with a programming problem** - I'd probably post it here and not there if I were you. The fact you already have a inefficient solution is good - it actually **shows you have attempted to do research** before asking.

Comment: It feels like a problem too local for SO unless it is using a known library or _maybe_ a very common algorithm.

Answer (score 17):

I would say Code Review as you want to make **working** code more efficient. If it wasn't working then it would be on topic here.

Comment: And if you roll interdisciplinary, true to the subject in question, http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/ might be relevant as well. If you are dealing with a relevant level of abstraction in your specific problem.

Comment: The OP's question sounds like an algorithm question. Couldn't http://cs.stackexchange.com/ be appropriate too?

Answer (score 2):

If the code does work, but you need more speed (a better implementation), [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) seems like the better place to ask, however most of these questions are on-topic on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) as well.

If you are looking to improve efficiency of your agent (a better algorithm), then [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), or [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) might be the better fit.

Comment: thank you. Never heard of Data Science before. May be I have to start AI proposal on Area 51 :-)